# Tower in Zorn's Lemma, Axiom of Choice

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

I am trying to understand how the Axiom of Choice implies Zorn's Lemma. A handout that I found to be rather easy to follow is [here](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/~fischer/215spring01/zorn.pdf).
The bit that I am stuck at is the tower.

In Halmos's Naive set theory, and other textbooks and handouts, the definition of tower comes without a warning and  I am left trying to figure out how it advances the proof.

My questions are:

- what the motivation behind the definition, what is the backstory that bring about the tower? What is it that we are trying to accomplish?
- Is it by taking intersection of towers, we obtain "one long chain" not unlike a rope that extend upward? and no "limbs" coming out from the rope that extend upwards as well?

I went through this link but still none the wiser in the end.
[Explanation of Proof of Zorn's lemma in Halmos's Book- II- Definition of towers and $\mathscr{X}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164862/explanation-of-proof-of-zorns-lemma-in-halmoss-book-ii-definition-of-towers?rq=1)

and I don't quite follow the answer given in
[Proof of Zorn's Lemma using the Axiom of Choice. Why is $\mathscr U$ a tower?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436504/proof-of-zorns-lemma-using-the-axiom-of-choice-why-is-mathscr-u-a-tower?rq=1)

Comment: That is the problem when you insist on avoiding ordinals. Some things just get complicated for no good reason.

Answer (score 4):

We're trying to find a maximal chain under inclusion, as indicated earlier. We're going to try and *build* one: an extremely long rope extending upwards, without branching. Ropes aren't easily composable, so the metaphor we'll use is a tower that we build layer by layer.

The way to build one is to repeatedly extend an existing tower by building another floor on top of it; this motivates the function $g$.

[The following paragraph amends item 1 in the definition of a tower: using $\emptyset$ instead of $\{ x \}$. I find this more obvious, but you can just skip this paragraph if you want to start with $\{x\}$.]

Now, we want to assume as little as possible about our poset, so ideally we just want to start off with a tiny chain and build up from there. The smallest chain is $\emptyset$, and we need a way to grow from there. We don't know anything else about our poset, so we'll just fix $x$ and say that $g(\emptyset) = \{ x \}$. (All told, this motivates item 1.)

To grow this chain $\{x\}$, we're obviously going to apply $g$, since that's our chain-growing procedure. Say it produces $\{x, y\}$. Then again, we'll grow the chain, and so on. (This motivates item 3.)

But now we've got arbitrarily large finite nested chains; how can we keep going to infinity? There's one obvious way: the chains are nested (and indeed each pair of chains has "one is an initial segment of the other"), so we can take the union. This is item 2.

---

A much more intuitive perspective is granted by the ordinals. We're performing recursion over the ordinals; item 3 gives us the definition on successor ordinals, and item 2 gives us the definition on limit ordinals. By Hartogs's lemma, the construction procedure must stop at some ordinal. The ~fischer document seems to be trying very hard to expunge the idea of the ordinals from the proof, but that's ultimately what's going on: Zorn is an attempt to build a copy of the ordinals inside a poset, and this is forbidden by Hartogs's Lemma.

---

The reason we need choice, by the way, is to decide any branching of our tower. At each stage, we might have several ways to extend the tower upwards; Choice lets us pick precisely one, so we end up with a single continuous tower at the end.